# Condense Rows by Comments Column

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table of data called `LogIndex` where a slice of it looks like this:

```
rowid   fruit   test    cat_id  start_time          end_time            result  comment
165     Apple   Peel    2590110 1/23/2014 0:20:35   1/23/2014 0:21:09   Remove  rotten
166     Apple   Peel    2590211 1/23/2014 0:26:35   1/23/2014 0:27:09   Remove  rotten
167     Apple   Peel    2590310 1/23/2014 0:32:35   1/23/2014 0:33:09   Remove  rotten
168     Apple   Peel    2590409 1/23/2014 0:38:35   1/23/2014 0:39:09   Remove  rotten
169     Apple   Peel    2590509 1/23/2014 0:44:35   1/23/2014 0:45:09   Remove  rotten
170     Apple   Peel    2590608 1/23/2014 0:50:35   1/23/2014 0:51:09   Remove  rotten
252     Apple   Peel    3516509 1/24/2014 1:56:35   1/24/2014 1:57:09   Remove  rotten
253     Apple   Peel    3516607 1/24/2014 2:02:35   1/24/2014 2:03:09   Remove  rotten
463     Apple   Peel    5485587 1/26/2014 22:56:35  1/26/2014 22:57:09  Remove  rotten
464     Apple   Peel    5485690 1/26/2014 23:02:35  1/26/2014 23:03:09  Remove  rotten
465     Apple   Peel    5485791 1/26/2014 23:08:35  1/26/2014 23:09:09  Remove  rotten
466     Apple   Peel    5485899 1/26/2014 23:14:35  1/26/2014 23:15:09  Remove  rotten
467     Apple   Peel    5486006 1/26/2014 23:20:35  1/26/2014 23:21:09  Remove  rotten
468     Apple   Peel    5486118 1/26/2014 23:26:35  1/26/2014 23:27:09  Remove  rotten
469     Apple   Peel    5486227 1/26/2014 23:32:35  1/26/2014 23:33:09  Remove  rotten
470     Apple   Peel    5486334 1/26/2014 23:38:35  1/26/2014 23:39:09  Remove  rotten
471     Apple   Peel    5486436 1/26/2014 23:44:35  1/26/2014 23:45:09  Remove  rotten
472     Apple   Peel    5486535 1/26/2014 23:50:35  1/26/2014 23:51:09  Remove  rotten
473     Apple   Peel    5486636 1/26/2014 23:56:35  1/26/2014 23:57:09  Remove  rotten
474     Apple   Peel    5486747 1/27/2014 0:02:35   1/27/2014 0:03:09   Remove  rotten
475     Apple   Peel    5486857 1/27/2014 0:08:35   1/27/2014 0:09:09   Remove  rotten
```

Where `rowid` = auto increment integer PK and `cat_id` is a FK for a different table.  The whole table where this data comes from has many more rows and is ordered by the `fruit` column and the `test` column in respect to the auto increment.  There can be any number of `fruit` values, but there is only ever eight types of `test` values.  There can also be an infinite amount of `comment` values (they are human-entered) though it is very likely that some values may be the same at various points in the data.

Basically, I am trying to write a view that would condense these rows down to something that looks like this:

```
rowid   fruit   test    cat_id  start_time              end_time                result  comment
165     Apple   Peel    2590110 1/23/2014 0:20:35       1/23/2014 0:51:09       Remove  rotten
252     Apple   Peel    3516509 1/24/2014 1:56:35       1/24/2014 2:03:09       Remove  rotten
463     Apple   Peel    5485587 1/26/2014 22:56:35      1/27/2014 0:09:09       Remove  rotten
```

Where I'd want the `MIN()` of `rowid`, the `MIN()` of `cat_id`, the `MIN()` of `start_time`, the `MAX()` of `end_time` where there is a consecutive block of rows where the `comment` values are all the same.

I know that `DLookUp("comment", "LogIndex", "rowid = " & rowid + 1)` will give me the next row's `comment` value to compare, so I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT rowid, fruit, type, MIN(cat_id), MIN(start_time), MAX(end_time), result, comment
FROM LogIndex
AND comment IS NOT NULL
AND result IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY fruit, type, rowid, result, comment, start_time, end_time
HAVING DLookup("comment", "LogIndex", "rowid = " & rowid + 1) = comment
ORDER BY fruit, type
```

Which doesn't condense anything except it leaves off the last row in the above sample (likely because rowid 171 has a blank or different comment than 170).

I have another query that *almost* works with the addition of a column joined from another table (`tsv`) that has a value for each year, month day and 24 hour for each row.  An example looks like `2014012300` for "1/23/2014 00:00:00".  The query looks like:

```
SELECT li.rowid, li.fruit, li.type, MIN(li.cat_id), MIN(li.start_time),MAX(tsv.end_time), li.result as vetting_results, li.comment
FROM LogIndex as li
INNER JOIN tsv ON tsv.cat_id = li.cat_id
WHERE li.result IS NOT NULL 
AND li.comment IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tsv.collection_id, li.fruit, li.type, li.result, li.comment, tsv.utc_start_datehr
ORDER BY tsv.collection_id, li.fruit, MIN(tsv.start_time), MAX(tsv.end_time);
```

The only thing about this query is that if there are any comments that aren't all under the same `utc_start_datehr` value, then they appear as hourly-divided rows.  For example, it would group the following rowids together: 463 to 473 and 474 to 475 in two separate rows.  I'd want 463 to be grouped down to 475 because they all sequentially (by rowid) have the same value for `comment`.

If there were some way for me to flag each individual row of the `LogIndex` table with a unique number grouped by clumps of `comment` values, then I am assuming that I could GROUP BY that method.

I'm open to using VBA if that is easier, but I'd like to avoid using an external dependency outside of Access unless it is impossible to do what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

The wording you're looking for here is that you want a "contiguous block" of data. This can also be called a "gaps and islands" problem as you are looking for "islands" of data with some shared property. There's a good page on dealing with contiguous blocks in SQL here: http://gcbenison.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/queries-that-group-tables-by-contiguous-blocks/

> "A simple GROUP BY statement will not do here, because we do not just want a single group of all rows matching our criteria; we want to preserve the order of the rows and find the first and last row of each contiguous block.  So how to do that, given that there is no “look at next row” or “look at last row” function in a SELECT statement?  The key is to join the table to itself, offset by one row."

Now this exact approach may not work for your problem, but reading up on this should help you to arrive at an answer. As with their solution here you may well need to join the table to itself and perform more analysis. If that fails then googling for "SQL contiguous blocks" or "SQL gaps and islands" will lead you closer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had forgotten that this question still existed.  I ended up creating a VBA function to create my contiguous block of data.  Your link has been bookmarked, and now I have specific language to use if this problem comes up again.

Comment: Glad to help. It might help other people for you to post your VBA function here as an answer. Also, please upvote my answer if it's been helpful :)